# How do I implement "share on Twitter" for photos on my website?

Tags: images, social-media, twitter, photo, share-this

I have a "share on Twitter" button on my website that allows users to easily share a tweet with the web page.  The page features a photo, and we would really like to have users tweet the photo itself out.

Is it possible to build "tweet this photo" functionality from my website?

If I fill the image URL into the tweet, Twitter shows a link to the image, but not the image itself.   Users can upload photo to twitter that get shown fully in Twitter.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I can think of is to use Twitter cards. This will mean though, that you would have to create a page for each image that you'd like Tweet-able - you may be able to get around this with some sort of lightbox iframe.

```
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="IMAGESOURCE">
```

It looks like a lot of people are searching for the same thing as you. Good luck implementing this - I'd be keen to know what solution you end up using.

Comment: Presumably I would have to include the URL in the suggested tweet and Twitter would send a bot out to crawl the page and discover the meta tag, then load the picture?

Comment: I'm already using `<meta property="og:image" content="...">` for Facebook which does something similar.  It would be nice if all the social sharing sites could standardize on a single meta tag for this.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/getting-started says that they should already be using open graph `og:` attributes if you don't have twitter specific ones.     I'm not sure why that isn't working then.